# Convert an Int value to an angle

Tags: android, int, angle, data-conversion

[image]How can we convert an Int value to an angle.

```
 int speed = remoteService.getSpeed();
```

I am getting the speed value from a remote service and I want to convert it to an angle.

How can I do this? Any Idea?

Comment: Which type of angle or what is the angle!! Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I have a speedometer in my program and I want to set the  needle according to the speed value, if the value of speed is 30 then I should show it in speedometer

Comment: So, it means you need to show Image?? (or something else)

Comment: No , I have a speedometer image and needle set in an horizontal position at 60 and I want to change the needle position according to the speed value. I am getting the speedvalue in a textview and updating it for every 1 sec. so If the speed value changes the needle should change its position according to that

Comment: Needle image is set to 60 by default and need to rotate it acording to the int value

Comment: I think you have to ROTATE needle image as per speed changes.

Answer (score 2):

public void getGenginePos(int state,float force, double AOD){
       double AODrad=(AOD*0.017444);

```
   switch(state){
       case BOAT_IDLE:
                //System.out.println("Before Vx = " + vx + ", vy = " + vy + ", f = " + force + ", AOD = " + AOD);
                vx = (float)(force * Math.cos(AODrad));
                px = px + (vx * dt);
                vy = (float) (force * Math.sin(AODrad));
                //System.out.println("After Vx = " + vx + ", vy = " + vy);

                py = py - (vy * dt);

                break;
        case BOAT_ACCEL:
                temp = force *dt;
                vx = (float) (force * Math.cos(AODrad) + temp);//(force * dt));
                vy = (float) (force * Math.sin(AODrad) + temp);//(force * dt));
                px = px + (vx * dt);
                py = py - (vy * dt);
                break;
        case BOAT_DECEL:
                temp = force *dt;
                vx = (float) (force * Math.cos(AODrad) - temp);//(force * dt));
                vy = (float) (force * Math.sin(AODrad) - temp);//(force * dt));
                px = px + (vx * dt);
                py = py - (vy * dt);
                break;
       default: break;

   }
}

public void setMeterPos(int rpx,int rpy,int epx,int epy){
   RefX= rpx;
   RefY= rpy;

   EndX = epx;
   EndY = epy;

   screenwidth=BoatRider.screenWidth;
   screenheight=BoatRider.screenHeight;
}

public void setArrowEndX(int x){
    EndX = x;
}
public void setArrowEndY(int y){
    EndY = y;
}
public float getArrowEndX(){
    return EndX;
}

public float getArrowEndY(){
    return EndY;
}

public void getGMeterArrowPos(double AOD,float radius){
    double AODrad=(AOD*0.017444);
    vx=(float)(radius*Math.cos(AODrad));
    vy=(float)(radius*Math.sin(AODrad));

    float height=screenheight-RefY;

    EndX = vx+RefX;
    EndY=screenheight-(vy+height);

}

public float getBorderEndX(){
   return EndX;
}
public float getBorderEndY(){
    return EndY;
}
public void getGBoatBorderPos(double AOD,float radius,float boderRefX,float boderRefY){
    double AODrad=(AOD*0.017444);
    vx=(float)(radius*Math.cos(AODrad));
    vy=(float)(radius*Math.sin(AODrad));

    float height=screenheight-boderRefY;

    EndX = vx+boderRefX;
    EndY=screenheight-(vy+height);

}
```

}
it will be very useful

Comment: its basic for speedometer code i use it while developing game

Answer (score 1):

```
int speed = 90;
double degrees = speed ;
double angle = degrees * 2 * Math.PI / 360.0;
```

Or you can use

```
int speed = 30;
 double degrees = speed;
 double toDegree = Math.toDegrees(radians);
```

Comment: how is that helpful in any way?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How can we set this angle to a bitmap image(needle) which I am using for the speedometer? so that needle will move according to the speed